# how to ignore index comparison for pandas assert frame equal

Tags: python, pandas

I try to compare below two dataframe with "check_index_type" set to False. According to the documentation, if it set to False, it shouldn't "check the Index class, dtype and inferred_type are identical". Did I misunderstood the documentation? how to compare ignoring the index and return True for below test?

I know I can reset the index but prefer not to.

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.testing.assert_frame_equal.html

```
from pandas.util.testing import assert_frame_equal
import pandas as pd
d1 = pd.DataFrame([[1,2], [10, 20]], index=[0,2])
d2 = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2], [10, 20]], index=[0, 1])
assert_frame_equal(d1, d2, check_index_type=False)


AssertionError: DataFrame.index are different
DataFrame.index values are different (50.0 %)
[left]:  Int64Index([0, 2], dtype='int64')
[right]: Int64Index([0, 1], dtype='int64')
```

Comment: does the assert yield 'False'?

Comment: Do you get `AssertionError` ?

Comment: @Lisa check my comment on Wen's answer

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Index is part of data frame , if the index are different , we should say the dataframes are different , even the value of dfs are same , so , if you want to check the value , using `array_equal` from `numpy`

```
d1 = pd.DataFrame([[1,2], [10, 20]], index=[0,2])
d2 = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2], [10, 20]], index=[0, 1])
np.array_equal(d1.values,d2.values)
Out[759]: True
```

For more info about `assert_frame_equal` in [git](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/19411)

Comment: To answer the assert_frame_equal part, the check_index_type is only ignoring the data type of the index, not the values themselves. So the flag is not equivalent to 'ignore index values'

Comment: This, however, will ONLY check the values, not e.g. column names. For a use case where only the index shouldn't be checked I think it is better to use assert_frame_equal(df1.reset_index(drop=True), ...)

Comment: This should work, but it's kind of annoying that it expects everything to be sorted identically. `pd.testing.assert_frame_equal` can handle that on its own.

Answer (score 63):

If you really don't care about the index being equal, you can drop the index as follows:

```
assert_frame_equal(d1.reset_index(drop=True), d2.reset_index(drop=True))
```

Comment: reset_index(drop=True) is not working.. are you sure? It is truncating the whole data frame.

Comment: `reset_index(drop=True)` should make the indices the same, but it creates a new index, it doesn't remove the index

Answer (score 11):

For those who came to this question because they're interested in using `pd.testing.assert_series_equal` (operates on `pd.Series`), pandas 1.1.0 has introduced an argument `check_index`:

```py
import pandas as pd
s1 = pd.Series({"a": 1})
s2 = pd.Series({"b": 1})
pd.testing.assert_series_equal(s1, s2, check_index=False)
```

This argument does not yet exist for `pd.testing.assert_frame_equals`.